# Почему консольный клиент FTP не умеет выполнять некоторые команды?

Tags: windows, ftp

Стандартный хелп клиента FTP:

```
ftp> help
Допускается сокращение команд при вводе.  Набор команд:

!               delete          literal         prompt          send
?               debug           ls              put             status
append          dir             mdelete         pwd             trace
ascii           disconnect      mdir            quit            type
bell            get             mget            quote           user
binary          glob            mkdir           recv            verbose
bye             hash            mls             remotehelp
cd              help            mput            rename
close           lcd             open            rmdir
```

Логинимся с пользователем и паролем и далее выполняем:

```
ftp> ls
500 PORT/EPRT (Active Mode/Extended Active Mode) is not supported. Use PASV/EPSV
 instead of this
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
Разрыв любых активных подключений...
425 Cannot open data connection.
```

Use PASV? Ок:

```
ftp> PASV
Недопустимая команда.
ftp> EPSV
Недопустимая команда.
```

Непонятно... пробуем снова:

```
ftp> ls
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
```

Здесь виснем намертво, пока не нажмем Ctrl+C

Причем при подключении через FileZilla смотрим список выполняемых команд:

```
Ответ:  230 User logged in.
Команда:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Ответ:  200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Статус: Соединение установлено
Статус: Получение списка каталогов...
Команда:    PWD
Ответ:  257 "/" is current directory.
Статус: Список каталогов "/" извлечен
```

Здесь и список файлов и передача - ОК, давайте повторим в консоли:

```
230 User logged in.
ftp> OPTS UTF8 ON
Недопустимая команда.
ftp> PWD
257 "/" is current directory.
ftp> ls
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
```

И опять замолчал до Ctrl+C...
WTF? У консольного клиента есть какие-то ограничения?

Comment: ftp клиент - это виндовый клиент?

Comment: @KoVadim да, это стандартный виндовый FTP клиент

Comment: он просто не умеет пассивный режим. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643542/how-to-use-passive-ftp-mode-in-windows-command-prompt

Comment: @KoVadim хорошо, почему OPTS UTF8 ON недопустимая команда? почему LS вместо обычного LIST?

Comment: Потому что этих команд нет в протоколе, например? Что это часть клиента, в других клиентах не работающая?

Comment: наверное потому, что в виндовом клиенте нельзя так просто передавать "ftp команды". А передаются "высокоуровневые". А почему так сделано... кто его знает. Может для домохозяек писалось

Comment: @KoVadim т.е. фактически это обертка, скрывающая настоящие команды? и тот самый help - это хелп инструкций этого конкретного клиента, а не команд FTP?

Comment: Думаю, что это так.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, думаю можно это оформлять как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

клиент ftp.exe - весь своеобразный. В нем многие вещи реализованы по своему (и help тому подтверждение). А также в нем нет пассивного режима - [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643542/how-to-use-passive-ftp-mode-in-windows-command-prompt).

Answer (score 0):

У меня касперский блокировал исполнение. Внес ftp.exe в исключения - всё заработало.

Comment: Касперский блокировал исполнение не всего бинарника, а отдельных команд? Это как так вообще?

Comment: @andreymal он перехватывает PORT команду и отвечает клиенту, что она не поддерживается, используйте Passive режим.